# How does value change in Golang Map of interface

Tags: dictionary, go, interface

This is the code base -
https://go.dev/play/p/BeDOUZ9QhaG

Output -

```
map[something:map[ACM:34.12 age:12 dune:dune]]
```

How does changing values in t variable affect in x?

```
package main

import "fmt"

    func main() {
        x: = make(map[string] interface {}, 10)
        x["something"] = map[string] interface {} {
            "dune": "dune", "age": 12
        }
    
        t: = x["something"].(map[string] interface {})
        t["ACM"] = 34.12
       

 fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Map types are reference types, like pointers or slices,

so this line

```
t := x["something"].(map[string]interface{}) t["ACM"] = 34.12 fmt.Println(x) }
```

is just a shallow copy creating `alias` for the existing map you created above in `x` variable ,so they are pointing to same memory address where the original map you created exists.

See for reference -https://go.dev/blog/maps